# Visual Studio 6 tips and tricks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vb6, ide

Some of us would invariably have to support 'legacy' code using Microsoft's Visual Studio 6.0 IDEs which - although opinions would differ - are generally regarded to be less user friendly compared to the later incarnations of the Visual Studio series of IDEs.

So I'd like to hear about some of your best hidden/poorly documented IDE features (could be for either C++ or VB). As is the usual practice one feature per post, please.

Comment: Since the VC++ IDE was completely different from the VB6 one, so there's no overlap in the tips, there's now a separate question for VB6 IDE tips http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664370/your-favorite-visual-basic-6-tools-and-tips

Comment: @casperOne Please reopen this question. It is constructive, it involves facts, references and specific expertise. There is no opinion, debate, arguments or extended discussion.

Comment: @MarkJ The act of using voting to determine the "best/worst" in order to facilitate a list question's validity is "not constructive".  Even if it *was* constructive, it would be closed as "not a real question" given the broad nature of the question.  [List questions are not appropriate for Stack Exchange, regardless of popularity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11780/140951) regardless of whether or not they fit a *singular* aspect of the FAQ.  It has to fit *all* aspects of the FAQ (and even then, others as well).

Comment: @MarkJ Additionally, the majority of these *aren't even answers*, and should be comments instead.

Comment: @casperOne Thank you for answering. The link you offer as explanation for why "list questions are not appropriate for SE" is just an answer on meta with +2 votes. Jon Skeet has an answer on the same question, that says they **are** OK, with +3 votes. But maybe you have a better link? And I can't see one answer here that's really a comment.

Comment: @MarkJ First, your vote tally is wrong.  Also, note that the *accepted* answer is the purview of the *person asking the question*, not necessarily the *answer that the community believes is the best*, which is why I linked you to Shog9's (someone who *works* for Stack Exchange, mind you) answer, where he supports *another* answer along the lines of it being inappropriate.  While I respect Jon's opinion on many things, I disagree with him on this.  Finally, if one was to consider Jon's answer as *the* answer, *none* of what he suggests should be done for questions like this is being done here.

Comment: @MarkJ Also, anything that currently has six votes or less generally is a comment.  It's just a short blurb of text and would be considered a comment on *any* other post in the system.

Comment: @MarkJ Finally, if you disagree with this question being closed, you are free to bring it up on meta.  However, note that the question can always be *reopened*, I assume that the current vote to reopen is yours.  Just find other's to reopen it who agree with you.  However, don't be surprised if it is flagged again and another moderator takes the same stance.  Closing/reopening is *how the system was intended to work*.

Answer (score 19):

Last time I had to use VB6, I wanted to jump out of my skin in anger because the **scroll wheel on my mouse**, which literally works with every other program in Windows, didn't work. This has something to do with the age of VB6 and how Microsoft has changed scroll wheel functionality over the years.

[This guy wrote a program to make it work.](http://www.joebott.com/vb6scrollwheel.htm)

(and it looks like in the years since Microsoft [made a fix as well](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837910))

Comment: It's also about mouse drivers. I've got proper ones, and have never had the scrolling problem in VB6 (and have always advised people to install proper drivers for their mice).

But in VBA, there was a problem indeed, and Microsoft fixed it in Office 2003 SP3.

Comment: Oh god, I've been developing in vb6 for the past 10 months, and not once could I find the scroll wheel fix. Just when I finished the project, I happen to stumble upon your answer. If I could upmod you 20 times, I would.

Comment: Yay, my terrible website made it into a Stack Overflow answer! And, it took me 1.5 years to notice.

Answer (score 12):

For VB6, [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) is a fantastic free add-in.  My favorite features are its find feature and its ability to find all callers of a given routine with a click of the button.  It has several other features as well, several of which I've found helpful on occasion.

Comment: Great tip! Made my life much easier on commenting and looking at unmaintainable function.

Comment: MZ-Tools has saved me a ton of time.  Spend some time configuring it.  You won't regret it.

Answer (score 9):

#### Custom Code Templates in VB6

I don't know if this is really a "hidden" feature or not, but always thought it was a nice time-saver.

You can create your own custom templates for classes, modules, forms, etc. and make them available in the IDE. For example, I usually like to use strongly-typed `Collection` classes in my VB6 code. So I might want a `FooCollection` that holds `Foo` objects and nothing else, instead of a plain old `Collection`. I don't want to have to reimplement the `Collection` interface every time I need a new strongly-typed `Collection`, so I created a new class template that contained all the boiler-plate `Collection` code. Now whenever I go to add a new class module to my project, my custom `TypedCollection` template is available as an option. Then I just rename the newly-added class `FooCollection` and replace all occurences of "As Object" with "As Foo" (where Foo is the type of object I want to store in the collection) and I'm done.

Keeping with my custom class template example, here's what you do:

1. Open up the IDE and start a new project (I usually just do Standard EXE, because it doesn't really matter what you pick here).
2. Add a new class to the project. This will become your template.
3. Code your template class. Basically just write any boiler-plate code that you would like to be able to reuse in other projects. This is straight VB code, nothing special.
4. When you're finished save your file in your `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB6\Template\Classes` folder (Note: the other subfolders, such as `Forms`, etc. are for other kinds of templates). The name of the .cls file minus the extension is what will appear in the IDE, so I normally include spaces in the file name for readability.
5. The next time you open up your IDE and click `Project->Add Class Module`, your template class will appear in the list of available class templates.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin\AUTOEXP.DAT` to add rules for displaying meaningful values of your custom classes in the Debug Watch Window.

What I mean is this.  We have a date structure defined like this:

```
typedef struct tagMHDATE
   {
   short int  nDay;      // Day of the Month  1..31
   short int  nMonth;    // Month of the Year 1..12
   short int  nYear;     // Year
   } MHDATE, FAR *LPMHDATE;
```

If I have this code:

```
MHDATE today;
GetDate(&today);
```

...and drop `today` in the watch window, I'll see something like this:

```
today    {...}
```

Now go and add this to the end of AUTOEXP.DAT (it's just a text file)

```
tagMHDATE=date=<nMonth>/<nDay>/<nYear>
```

...and now I see this in the Watch window:

```
today    {date=10/8/2008}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'll kick this off a VS C++ feature which has saved me lots of time: appending a ",su" (without the quotes) to a unicode string in the watch window of a debugger enables you to view the value of the string (rather than the memory address of that string)

Answer (score 6):

The **Erl** function in VB6.  If you put line numbers in your VB6 code, you can, in your error handler, access the line number at which your error occurred via the return value of the function **Erl**.

Comment: You can put the line numbers and/or error handlers in automatically with a free tool like MZTools. http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few tips and tricks [here](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/visualstudio.html). My favorite one is placing `@err,hr`
in the Watch window to get error messages.

Answer (score 4):

For VC6, get a copy of [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/purchase/default.asp) by Whole Tomato.  It contains a smart (and usable) Intellisense replacement, much richer code coloring, some refactoring support, and many more features.  Most definitely worth the investment.

Answer (score 4):

Change the "Start in" property on the shortcut that you use to start VB6 to the root of your source code directory.  This will save many wasted mouse clicks every time you open a  project from within the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

CodeShine: VB6 code refactoring add-in (free). Includes refactorings such as Extract Method, Introduce Explaining Variable, Extract Function, Introduce Explaining Variable, Rename, etc

http://www.wsdesigns.com/CodeShine/default.htm

Comment: Looks interesting, and may well be worth purchasing, but it's not free - it costs $75.

Answer (score 2):

Quick macros was always a personal favorite of mine; not really a hidden feature per-se, but very useful, and VC6 was the last version where they were quick enough to be useful (before MS rewrote the macro engine to use .NET).

Comment: Could you describe how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Shift-Alt-Enter to increase the size of the editor window

Answer (score 0):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154661/pre-setting-locations-for-looking-for-source-files-in-visual-c-60#173240) to the question ["If you are not satisfied with answers on someone else’s question, should you start your own?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184930/if-you-are-not-satisfied-with-answers-on-someone-elses-question-should-you-star) shows how to pre-populate VC++ with all your source paths. It's useful for those of us who build from the command line, but debug using msdev.

Comment: Don't you mean your answer to the question "Pre-setting locations for looking for source files in Visual C++ 6.0"  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154661/pre-setting-locations-for-looking-for-source-files-in-visual-c-60#173240 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a VB6 IDE feature, but if you have to fill an unbound listview with a lot of data then making it invisible during the filling process speeds it up by maybe a factor of 10.

Comment: how do you make a listview invisible?

Comment: Just:

listview.visible = false

then iterate through your recordset populating the listview manually

then listview.visible = true once complete.

Only really applies if you use a listview unbound, which I tend to.